# How to make two different functions work on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, fixed, sticky, window-resize

I want to make a sticky banner, which becomes fixed at top when it is scrolled and unsticks at the end of the page. The document height is dependent upon images, that's why I use window load event. I have the following code:

```
  function saleBanner() {
    $(window).bind("load", function() {
      // Make sale banner fixed-at-top
      var s = $('.sale-container');
      var pos = s.offset();
      var maxTop = $(document).outerHeight() - 828 - s.outerHeight(); // 828 is the total height of site footer and sign up form

      function fixedBanner() {
        var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (currentTop >= pos.top && currentTop < maxTop) {
          s.attr("style", ""); //kill absolute positioning
          s.addClass('fixed-at-top'); //stick it
        } else if (currentTop >= maxTop) {
          s.removeClass('fixed-at-top'); //un-stick
          s.css({bottom: 0}); //set sticker right above the footer
        } else {
          s.removeClass('fixed-at-top'); //top of page
        }
      }
      $(window).scroll(fixedBanner);
    });
  }

  saleBanner();
```

I want to make this function work on window resize as well. So I added the following code:

```
  function resizeBanner() {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    if (viewportWidth > 767) {
      saleBanner();
    }
  }
```

I have one more function `resizeWindow` for mobile menu, which I also need to work on window resize. So when I put this two functions together, they don't work (although they work on window resize separately):

```
  $(window).resize(function(e) {
    resizeWindow(e);
    resizeBanner(e);
  });
```

Where is my mistake? How can I make both functions work on window resize?

**Update**: Here is the whole code for `resizeWindow` function. It's rather long, but may be it would be helpful for the answer.

```
  // Mobile menu
  var MQM = 768;
  var viewportWidth = $(window).width();

  function navSlide() {
    var headerHeight = $('.cd-header').height();
    $(window).on('scroll', {previousTop: 0}, function () {
      var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      //check if user is scrolling up
      if (currentTop < this.previousTop ) {
        //if scrolling up...
        if (currentTop > 0 && $('.cd-header').hasClass('is-fixed')) {
          $('.cd-header').addClass('is-visible');
        } else {
          $('.cd-header').removeClass('is-visible is-fixed');
        }
      } else {
        //if scrolling down...
        if(!$('.cd-header').hasClass('menu-is-open')) {
          $('.cd-header').removeClass('is-visible');
        }
        if( currentTop > headerHeight && !$('.cd-header').hasClass('is-fixed')) $('.cd-header').addClass('is-fixed');
      }
      this.previousTop = currentTop;
    });
  }

  // Primary navigation slide-in effect on load
  if(viewportWidth < MQM) {
    navSlide();
  }

  function addOverflow() {
    $('html').addClass('overflow-hidden');
    $('body').addClass('overflow-hidden');
  }

  function removeOverflow() {
    $('html').removeClass('overflow-hidden');
    $('body').removeClass('overflow-hidden');
  }

  function hideHeader() {
    $('.cd-header').removeClass('is-fixed is-visible');
  }

  function hideMenu() {
    $('.cd-header').removeClass('menu-is-open is-fixed is-visible');
    $('.cd-menu-icon').removeClass('is-clicked');
  }

  function resizeWindow() {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    $(window).off('scroll'); // unbind scroll event
    if (viewportWidth > 767) {
      if ($('.cd-primary-nav').hasClass('is-visible')) {
        if ($('.algolia__search-content').hasClass('algolia__search-content--active')) {
          hideMenu();
          $('.search-trigger').addClass('is-clicked');
          $('.search-header').addClass('is-fixed');
        } else {
          hideMenu();
          if (!$('.js-algolia__input').is(':focus')) {
            $('.cd-primary-nav').removeClass('is-visible').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',function(){
              removeOverflow();
            });
            $('.search-trigger').removeClass('is-clicked');
            $('.search-header').removeClass('is-fixed');
          } else {
            $('.search-trigger').addClass('is-clicked');
            $('.search-header').addClass('is-fixed');
          }
        }
      } else {
        hideHeader();
      }
    } else {
      navSlide();
      if ($('.cd-primary-nav').hasClass('is-visible')) {
        $('.cd-header').addClass('menu-is-open');
        $('.cd-menu-icon').addClass('is-clicked');
        $('.search-trigger').removeClass('is-clicked');
        $('.search-header').removeClass('is-fixed');
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: How are you re sizing your window on mobile?

Comment: Can you post the code of the `resizeWindow` function?

Comment: The reason behind asking the question was, I believe the re size method will trigger only when we re size the browser window. I want to know how the re size event will trigger in mobile? Just a curiosity.

Comment: this is not an answer but have you checked out twitter bootstrap? all this resizing stuff is handled extremely well using bootstrap.

Comment: @suyesh I guess it triggers when you resize the browser window as well as orientation of iPad, for example. On iPad with landscape orientation we have the same design as on desktop, and the banner is fixed. And on iPad with portrait orientation we have responsive design for tablet, i. e. the banner is hidden.

Comment: @JamesMcCormac thank you for your reply, but we are not using bootstrap on our site.

Comment: @jupiteror No problem. I will have a look through your code and see if I can spot anything.

Comment: @JamesMcCormac Ok, thank you very much!

Comment: You should be using media queries in CSS for almost (if not) everything here - using JavaScript to do this is extremely inefficient and difficult to maintain

Comment: @OwenAyres Yes, I'm using media queries. I use JavaScript only for the things, that can't be done with CSS. You can see a working example here http://www.iloveip.ru. Try, for example, resizing a browser window with search open or use mobile menu.